# Get Number Group of Regex Python

Tags: python, regex

So, i got some string that i want to get a pattern, the string has slight variation that can be string1 or string2

```
string1 = """
    Rak penyimpanan berbentuk high chest dengan gaya American Country.  Cocok digunakan untuk menyimpan 
segala keperluan hunian Anda! Dibuat dengan rangka kayu mahoni, papan mdf dan finishing cat duco berkualitas.  Kualitas ekspor akan menjamin kepuasan 
Anda.  Dikirim jadi, tanpa perakitan. Panjang 76 cm Kedalaman 40 cm Tinggi 120 cm
"""

string2 = """
    Rak penyimpanan berbentuk high chest dengan gaya American Country.  Cocok digunakan untuk menyimpan 
segala keperluan hunian Anda! Dibuat dengan rangka kayu mahoni, papan mdf dan finishing cat duco berkualitas.  Kualitas ekspor akan menjamin kepuasan 
Anda.  Dikirim jadi, tanpa perakitan. P 76 cm L 40 cm T 120 cm
"""
```

What i want to achieve is to capture group pattern and get (51, 23, 47-89)
What i have done is create a pattern like this

```
pattern = (\bP|Panjang\b).+(\d)+.+(\bL|Kedalaman\b).+(\d)+.+(\bT|Tinggi\b).+(\d)+.[cm]+
```

i have tried it in https://regexr.com/ but the group only capture the last digit such as (1,3,9)
What am i missing, cause i already put + after the \d in every group ?

Comment: sorry, i mess the analogy, let me give the real text

Comment: Put the `+` inside the `()`: `(\d+)`

Comment: still get the last number, this is the pattern: (\bP|Panjang\b).+(\d+)+.+(\bL|Kedalaman\b).+(\d+)+.+(\bT|Tinggi\b).+(\d+)+.[cm]+

Comment: A capture group can only capture one match. If you quantify a group, it captures the last match.

Comment: i learn from this website that you can capture digit with group   https://pynative.com/python-regex-capturing-groups/#:~:text=Capturing%20groups%20are%20a%20handy,will%20be%20a%20capture%20group.

Comment: `(\d+)+` makes no sense. `\d+` already captures multiple digits. Repeating the group won't capture any more.

Comment: The problem is also putting `.+` before `(\d+)`. `.+` will match the starting digits. Use a non-greedy quantifier: `.+?(\d+)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can:

- change the `.+` to be more specific like `\scm\s` or `\s`
- You can just match `cm` instead of using a character class `[cm]+` that might also match `ccc`
- If you only want the digits, you can omit the capture groups around the names

For example

```
\bP(?:anjang)?\s(\d+)\scm\s(?:L|Kedalaman)\s(\d+)\scm\sT(?:inggi)?\s(\d+)\scm\b
```

**Explanation**

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial word match
- `P(?:anjang)?\s` Match `P`  and optionally `anjang`
- `(\d+)\scm\s` Capture 1+ digits in **group 1**, and match  `cm`
- `(?:L|Kedalaman)\s` Match `L`  or `Kedalaman`
- `(\d+)\scm\s` Capture 1+ digits in **group 2** and match  `cm`
- `T(?:inggi)?\s` Match `T`  and optionally `inggi`
- `(\d+)\scm` Capture 1+ digit in **group 3** and match  `cm`
- `\b` A word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kgvWGc/1)

Answer (score 2):

##### Regex

```py
"(?:P|Panjang)\s(?P<P>\d+)\scm\s(?:L|Kedalaman)\s(?P<L>\d+)\scm\s(?:T|Tinggi)\s(?P<T>\d+)\scm"g
```

##### About Regex:

- See [Regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/NtQpEB/1)
- captures three groups: `P`, `L` and `T`
- groups should have the digits match.

Answer (score 0):

```
\bP(?:anjang)?\s([\d-]+)\s(?:cm|m)?(?:\s)?(?:L|Kedalaman)?\s([\d-]+)\s(?:cm|m)?(?:\s)?T(?:inggi)?\s([\d-]+)\s(?:cm|m)?\b
```

- `(?:)` non-capturing group
- `\b`  A word boundary
- `P(?:anjang)?` Match P and or Panjang
- `\s` is whitespace
- `([\d-]+)` Match 123 or 123-456
- `(?:cm|m)?` Match cm or m or nothing
- `(?:\s)?` Match Whitespace or nothing
- `(?:L|Kedalaman)?` Match L or Kedalaman
- `T(?:inggi)?` Match T and or Tinggi